# Pip installing a whl-file from a private github repository

Tags: python, github, installation, pip

How can one install a .whl (python library) from a private github repo?

I have setup a personal access token and can install the library if its not a .whl by using the following command

```
pip install git+https://{token}@github.com/{org_name}/{repo_name}.git
```

However if there is a .whl in the repo and I want to install from that using:

```
pip install git+https://{token}@github.com/{org_name}/{repo_name}/blob/master/{name.whl}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

I am stumped! You can pip install {name.whl} if the file is locally but not from the private github repo.

Quesiton: How to pip install name.whl on a private github repo?

Comment: ...is there a particular reason you can't just download the repo and run on the local file?

Comment: I need to automate it accross multiple machines and need a very easy, user friendly way.

Comment: you can simply download file and then install from local `.whl`

Comment: @JacquesJoubert

The error may not be with GitHub. It may be due to some issue in the path.

Can you verify the path-building procedure. For example,  the variable {name.whl} may be None.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
pip install https://{token}@raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/master/{name.whl}
```

Comment: How do you do this for ssh? I tried `pip install git+ssh://git@raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/master/{name.whl}` to no avail

Answer (score -2):

you should add the option -e to indicate that you are using a url :

```
pip install -e git+https://{token}@github.com/{org_name}/{repo_name}/blob/master/{name.whl}
```

Comment: I did try this and play around with it but sadly couldn't get it working.

Comment: The -e option is used to install a project in **editable** mode, not to indicate a url. See the [pip install options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options)